# An alternative to cache_choices in django 1.8.1 to get rid of RemovedDjango1.9 cache_choices deprecation warning in forms

Tags: django, django-forms, django-1.8

I have been using cache_choices option in django ModelChoiceField to cache my queryset responses something like:

```
university = forms.ModelChoiceField(label='University', cache_choices=True, widget=forms.Select(
    attrs={'class': 'ac-university'}), queryset=University.objects.none(), empty_label="--- None ---", help_text="", error_messages={'required': 'University field required.'})
```

I am getting a lot of warnings like:

```
...events/forms.py:400: RemovedInDjango19Warning: cache_choices has been deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.9.
 language_prefered = forms.ModelChoiceField(cache_choices=True, widget = forms.Select(attrs = {}), queryset = Language.objects.order_by('name'), empty_label = "--- None ---", error_messages = {'required':'Language field required.'})
```

I am looking for an alternative for this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It may not be the answer you were looking for but it looks like there isn't an alternative.

From the [deprecation ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22838):

> The current implementation of `cache_choices` is pretty useless as it does not share between multiple forms, only between multiple renderings of the same form object. This is because of how we copy fields when moving from `form.base_fields` to `form.fields`. As such, `cache_choices` as is should be removed.

So unless you were rendering the same form object multiple times, it looks as though it might not have been doing what you wanted anyway.